# PHP and MySQL select records from one table that don't exist in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, the first is called `new_account` and the other is called `new_record`.

The table `new_account` contains the information of registered user and the table `new_record` contain the information of the users from `new_account` table who has paid and the months in which they have paid.

I want to be able to see the users who hadn't paid according to the month and year entered through the input. Here is the PHP I'm using:

```
$query= 'SELECT * FROM   new_account LEFT OUTER JOIN new_record 
                      where month=$_POST[month] and year =$_POST[year] 
                      ON (new_account.mbere = new_record.mbere)
                      WHERE new_record.mbere IS NULL ';
```

Comment: Please format the code in your question properly

Comment: thank you i have done it

Comment: (1) you have 2 `WHERE` clauses, which is invalid syntax. (2) php variables inside single quotes are not parsed.

Comment: I got an error. can you help me by giving a working query please

Answer (score 1):

For what I can understand from your query this should at least fix your syntax.

```
$query= 'SELECT * 
FROM  new_account 
LEFT OUTER JOIN new_record ON new_account.mbere = new_record.mbere 
WHERE new_record.mbere IS NULL AND month='.$_POST['month'].' AND year = '.$_POST['year'].';
```

You cannot have more than one WHERE clause in your query so I grouped them togheter. I also fixed variable escaping for single quotes

Comment: This is giving me an error also :Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Comment: Without looking at your data I could only fix the query syntax. This query is simply not returning any data. Are you going to improve your question with some info to solve the content part?

Comment: Is there any other way i can use?What I am trying to get is the users who are in new_account table whose payment information is not in new_record    at a certain month and year

Answer (score 0):

The structure of statement should be like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM new_account
    LEFT JOIN new_record
    ON new_account.mbere=new_record.mbere
    WHERE new_record.mbere IS NULL
    AND new_recor.month ='$_POST[month]'
    AND new_recor.year = '$_POST[year]';
```

The query for this should be used as this:

```
    $month = $_POST[month];
    $year = $_POST[year];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM new_account LEFT JOIN new_record ON new_account.mbere=new_record.mbere WHERE new_record.mbere IS NULL AND new_record.month ='$month' AND new_record.year = '$year'";
```

Comment: You should add a new column of time in new_record table at which that entry has made. That can be done by php function date("h:i:sa"). Then you should make a check on this column by condition. Then you can get the not payed people of that time.